# Consulta com campo do tipo json no Doctrine 2 e Symfony 3

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, symfony

Alguem sabe uma forma de realizar um consulta usando Doctrine a qual possui um campo JSON?

Exemplo de consulta no Postgresql:

```
select id, nome, tipo, '{"idUsuario":465,"login":"paulo"}'::json
from public.usuarios
limit 5;
```

Preciso fazer essa consulta no Doctrine 2, alguém sabe como?

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende um pouco da forma como seu sistema está modelado. Você está usando o `EntityManager` para mapear suas classes em tabelas, ou não?

Se sim, há um bundle que resolve isso: https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle. Você diz que aquela propriedade é do tipo `jsonb` e faz as consultas da forma que o bundle te instrui.

Caso você esteja usando o DBAL, já existe suporte para isso, como é possível ver na tabela de mapeamentos do Doctrine: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix

Por fim, se nenhuma das soluções acima ajudar, você ainda pode usar a função `createNativeQuery` para executar uma função nativa daquele banco de dados em especial e ter um um array de resultados como retorno.